# How to make a Secure connection between an external database and an EC2-Server permanently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 server and I want to connect it to an external database permanently. We asked the database provider to open the firewall for our server however we are concern about the security of this connection. Is there some way to make this connection as secure as possible? Shall we setup something like VPN?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: VPN : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html

Comment: What database are you running and where? I.e MySQL and in data center

Comment: What is your specific concern about the security of this arrangement?  Is your database connection using SSL now?

Comment: @NHol One is MSSQL and one is Oracle

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot forexample data can be changed along the way, there is no integrity check on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need, you could set up a VPN from AWS to your external database, and if you're a heavyweight company you could even go to DirectConnect.